# oracle hierarchy query error ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table called ***abc***
columns and data are like:-

```
a    b    c
------------
ab   1    2
bc   2    3
cd   3    4
de   4    5
```

maybe there is data for cyclic like-

```
ef   5    1
```

i want output as:-

```
A   b    d
------------
ab  1    5/4/3/2/1
bc  2     5/4/3/2
cd  3     5/4/3
de  4      5/4
ef  5       5
```

please help me out find a query to retrive data like this

Answer (score 0):

You may use `listagg` with `select level from dual connect by level <= ?` statement, and do not need column `c`( and column `a` is only needed for *output* ), as in the following routine :

```
create table tab( a varchar2(2), b int );

insert all
       into tab values('ab',1) 
       into tab values('bc',2)
       into tab values('cd',3)
       into tab values('de',4)
       into tab values('ef',5)
select * from dual;

select a, b, 
      ( select listagg(6-level,'/') within group (order by level)
          from dual
        connect by level <= 6-b ) as d
  from tab t;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcf43/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  my_data(a,b,c) AS (
    select 'ab', 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 'bc', 2, 3 from dual union all
    select 'cd', 3, 4 from dual union all
    select 'de', 4, 5 from dual union all
    select 'ea', 5, 1 from dual   
  )  
  select a, b, sys_connect_by_path(b, '/') d
    from my_data t
  connect by nocycle c = prior b
    start with c = 1
    order by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a recursive CTE with a `CYCLE` clause to avoid cyclic data

```
WITH cte(a, b, c, d) AS
  ( SELECT a,
           b,
           c,
           to_char(b) AS d
    FROM abc
   WHERE c = 1
   UNION ALL SELECT t.a,
                    t.b,
                    t.c,
                    cte.d ||'/'||t.b
    FROM abc t
   JOIN cte ON (cte.b = t.c) ) 
CYCLE b SET CYCLE TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT a,
       b,
       d
FROM cte
WHERE CYCLE = 0
ORDER BY b ;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12479/16)